# Reformat a text file so it can be used a numpy array, in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a small chunk of code that i'm using to find the confidence interval from a data set.

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

a = np.loadtxt("test1.txt")
mean, sigma = np.mean(a), np.std(a)

conf_int = stats.norm.interval(0.95, loc=mean,
    scale=sigma)

print(conf_int)
```

However, my text file (test1.txt) is a list of numbers that a) has a square bracket at the start and finish b)is not in equal columns.

"[-10.197663   -22.970129   -15.678419   -15.306197
-12.09961    -11.845362   -18.10553    -25.370747
-19.34831    -22.45586]

np.loadtxt really doesn't seem to like this, so is there any way i can use a function to either read and use the data as is or reformat it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Update so i manged to remove my brackets with the code below

```
with open('test1.txt', 'r') as my_file:
text = my_file.read()
text = text.replace("[", "")
text = text.replace("]", "")


with open('clean.txt', 'w') as my_file:
my_file.write(text)


a = np.loadtxt("clean.txt")
mean, sigma = np.mean(a), np.std(a)

conf_int = stats.norm.interval(0.95, loc=mean,
   scale=sigma)

print(conf_int)
```

Just need to reformat clean.txt so its in one single column now so np.array will recognise it.

**Final update**

I managed to get it working, using @David Hoffman suggested code and my long work around from above; see below

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

with open('test1.txt', 'r') as my_file:
    text = my_file.read()
    text = text.replace("[", "")
    text = text.replace("]", "")


with open('clean.txt', 'w') as my_file:
    my_file.write(text)


a = np.array(list(map(float, text.strip("[]").split())))
mean, sigma = np.mean(a), np.std(a)

conf_int = stats.norm.interval(0.95, loc=mean,
   scale=sigma)

print(conf_int)
```

Thank you to everyone for taking the time to help, it was very much appreciated, especially to a new coder like me.

Comment: You can use ordinary Python text processing to load the strings, strip off brackets and quotes (if needed), split numbers etc.  But to step back a bit.  What was the source of this file?  Something you generated earlier, or were given?

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back to me. The file is one I've generated as part of a larger script. I'm pretty new to python and I've been working on it for the better part of a month. I've tried for a couple of days to change the output so the text file is formatted but I believe that it would be easier to do it the other way. Although I'm not sure. You said I could use pyhon text processing to strip off the brackets and reformat could you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import requests

link = "https://pastebin.pl/view/raw/929f5228"

response = requests.get(link)
text = response.text

# with open("test1.txt", "r") as my_file:
#     text = my_file.read()

a = np.array(list(map(float, text.strip("[]").split())))

mean, sigma = np.mean(a), np.std(a)

conf_int = stats.norm.interval(0.95, loc=mean, scale=sigma)

print(conf_int)
```

The commented lines are for if you have a file.

There's a lot packed into the string handling line:

1. The text string is cleaned (removing brackets)
2. The clean text is split by white space (any length of consecutive whitespace characters are treated as delimiters)
3. Each split token is converted to a `float` (this is the `map` part)
4. The `map` generator is converted to a list and passed to the `numpy` array function

As @Dishin said, there's some weirdness with how your input file is formatted. If you have any control over how the file is written (say from a LabVIEW program or other Python script) it might be worth formatting the data in a more widely accepted format like `.csv` so that functions like `np.loadtxt` (or programs like Excel) can read it more easily.

If you're stuck with the files as is you can just make a little utility function like:

```
def loader(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as my_file:
        text = my_file.read()

    return np.array(list(map(float, text.strip("[]").split())))
```

to reuse in your scripts.

Comment: Hi 

Thank you so much for getting back to me and giving me such a thorougher answer! 
However, every time i try the first code you suggested i get an error 

line 8, in <module>
    a = np.array(list(map(float, text.strip("[]").split())))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ']'

Is there anything you could suggest?

Comment: @Amy it looks like the file you’re working with is different from the one you posted on pastebin. Could you post the file that’s giving the issue? Could you also update your post to show the code that generates the file?

Answer (score 1):

You can read it as string then replace space with `,` to make it like list and
use `eval` to convert string list to `list` type and at last to numpy array.
For your given dummy input

```
li = """[-10.197663 -22.970129 -15.678419 -15.306197
-12.09961 -11.845362 -18.10553 -25.370747
-19.34831 -22.45586]"""

np.array(eval(li.replace(' ',',')))
array([-10.197663, -22.970129, -15.678419, -27.405807, -11.845362,
       -18.10553 , -44.719057, -22.45586 ])
```

For given input file - [here](https://pastebin.pl/view/929f5228) solution would be

```
import re
li = open('test1.txt', 'r').read()

np.array(eval(re.sub(r'(\n +| +)',',',li)))
array([-10.197663  , -22.970129  , -15.678419  , -15.306197  ,
        -0.38851437, -12.09961   , -11.845362  , -18.10553   ,
       -25.370747  , -20.575884  , -19.34831   , -22.45586   ,
       -31.209     , -19.68507   , -31.07194   , -28.4792    ,
        ...])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your help! BUT I keeping getting an error ,unexpected EOF while parsing - which i think is due to the way i'm indenting....i'm not sure

Comment: Could you post the `txt` file?

Comment: Sure! here you go https://pastebin.pl/view/929f5228

Comment: @AmyD3 please check i have updated my answer for given input file. Also NOTE at end of the file you are missing `]` en close square bracket which may cause `unexpected EOF` exception so try new solution after fixing that.